# Solving system of equations with row operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this example of solving a system of equations with row operations and I do not understand the step marked in red: [image: solving a system of equations with row operations.]

Could anyone offer some help please?

Kind regards
Stany

Comment: It seems it uses $2\times L_2 +3\times L_3$

Comment: $R_3 \to 3R_3+2R_2$.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Lucas

Comment: Thanks guys! @peterwhy

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}R_3 \rightarrow 3R_3 + 2R_2\end{align}
Thanks to @Lucas and @peterwhy